# SQL Server : merge cells based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have some raw data in staging environment in a SQL Server database. It doesn't have any primary key/unique constraints.

I am trying to clean data and get from one format to another format.

Example, if you look at row 1 and 2, I want the title "Interior-Tr" and "im" to be merged into "Interior-Trim" and Description of the two rows concatenated.

The first two rows of the sources data, should be the first row of the expected output

Could someone help me with how to change to required format (one set of sample data attached)?

Current table format

[image: input table data]

Output format

[image: output format].

Comment: What have you managed so far? And what are you stuck on?

Comment: its like I removed unnecessary records from my first draft version, and I am not sure how can I merge cells, I could do that if I have all the IDs are populated @DaleK

Comment: I am not looking for complete code, I am just looking for some idea to do this

Comment: Could you please give us your sample data as a text instead of an image?

Comment: Please find the excel file here https://easyupload.io/04022k

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple example of when to use lead/lag - I'm assuming you've managed to import this and retain the correct order (in future I suggest adding a row-number on import - I've simulated this for now):

--SETUP--

```
create table table1 (
      SheetNumber varchar (255) null
    , ID integer null
    , Title varchar(255) null
    , Reasonv varchar(255) null
    , Description varchar (255) null
    , Qty1 integer null
    , UOM varchar(255) null
    , UnitPrice varchar(255) null
    , TotalPrice varchar(255) null
)

insert into table1 values(2,3165257,'Interior-Tr','ReplaceMissing','Descrption Line 1','30','LF','1.17','35.1')
insert into table1 values(2,NULL,'im',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
insert into table1 values(2,3165252,'Demo-Dumpst','ReplaceMissing','Descrption Line 1','1','LS','478.26','478.26')
insert into table1 values(2,NULL,'er',NULL,'Descrption Line 2',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
insert into table1 values(2,3165263,'Demo-Structure','ReplaceMissing','Descrption Line 1','1','LS','30','30')
insert into table1 values(2,3165267,'Paint-Inter','ReplaceMissing','Descrption Line 1','2592','SF','1.04','2695.68')
insert into table1 values(2,NULL,'ior',NULL,'Descrption Line 2',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
insert into table1 values(2,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Descrption Line 3',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

--SOLUTION FRAMEWORK--

```
select * from (

    select 
          ID
        , Title as old_title
        , lead(Title) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) as lead_title
        , case
            when (ID is null) then title
            else concat(Title, lead(Title) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)))
            end as combined_title

     from table1) subQuery

where ID is not null
```